# how to open multiple ADOconnection in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Ubs.jpg

i want to use 4 select statements to get records from  4 separate tables in a database in sql server  in inno code and i am using four connection strings as below

```
ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');

    ADOConnection.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +
      'Data Source='+ DBPage.Values[0] + ';' +

     'Integrated Security=SSPI;';

    ADOConnection.Open;

ADOConnection2 := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');

    ADOConnection2.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +
      'Data Source='+ DBPage.Values[0] + ';' +

     'Integrated Security=SSPI;';

    ADOConnection2.Open;
```

like above i have opened 4 connections . while running the setup i am getting error message as 'there is no enough space to open connections'
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: In your code you're obviously connecting to the same database. You use the same data source `DBPage.Values[0]`. But let's ignore a possible typo in your question and let's focus on the error. A basic web search returns many possible reasons to get this message, but many of them focuses on a single connection and problem with the fetched recordset. When exactly this error occurs in your script ? I guess you are returning more rows than you actually want or that just the query you're running is not what you want. Btw. before we continue, *think about accepting answers for your old questions*.

Comment: in the query i am using count(*) to get the no of records which is a numeric and all query always fetch one row

Comment: Try to narrow the problem. I don't want to believe this would be a ADO connection instance count problem (of course each connecting to a different database).

Comment: this error comes when i keep clicking on the next button in the wizard where i have inputs for database authentication. i am showing a message if a  table in the database does not have a record . if i click once more i am getting the same message which want to display but when i click 3rd time on the wizard i am getting the error which i have attached

Comment: We have absolutely no clue what's going on in your next button clicks, what's your database or a query that you run. That's our starting point. You know all of that. Debug your code. [`Set a breakpoint`](http://i.imgur.com/7C0yn7q.png) and step through the code and see which line of your code, which query (or a connection, if you think) raises the exception. My best guess is that it's related to a single connection and a query that returns a recordset that hit the issue in the ADO. But I can be wrong. Btw. connecting to the same database as you shown in your code is a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

I began getting that error when I switched to the Unicode version of Inno. I switched back to the ANSI version and haven't seen the error since.

Comment: i think i am facing the same issue as i am using unicode version of inno

Comment: I've been using Unicode Inno Setup with ADO for a long time and never noticed error like this. This post is nothing more than an observation that something went wrong with a wild guess as a "solution". @Manas, if you can't even narrow and describe what was wrong how can someone help ? ADO has a several issues and you weren't even able to say your version of OS, ADO and if you can reproduce it with single connection. My help is over here. Good luck!